# Update JMenu display names

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model

So I have a JMenu with a few submenus inside.  The names of those menus are set by getting the name of a 1 of 4 players.  I added a MenuListener to the JMenu to update those names using

```
menu.setName(player.getName());
```

However, the name is changing but the update is not displaying in the menu.  How do I get the menu to update it's display?

```
editMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

       public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
          updateMenu();       
       }

       public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
       }

       public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
       } 
});
```

and updateMenu method:

```
public void updateMenu()
{
    partOneMenu.setName(Participant1.getName());
    partTwoMenu.setName(Participant2.getName());
    partThreeMenu.setName(Participant3.getName());
    partFourMenu.setName(Participant4.getName());

    partOneMenu.revalidate();

    partTwoMenu.revalidate();
    partThreeMenu.revalidate();
    partFourMenu.revalidate();

    System.out.println(partOneMenu.getName());
}
```

The print statement is showing that the name has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what exactly you want (a snapshot could have been useful), then you should use `menu.setText("player1")`

`setName(string)` is not for display, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227143/java-what-is-java-awt-component-getname-and-setname-used-for/227304#227304).