# Syntax for Java GUI component names?

Tags: java, user-interface, syntax, fitnesse

GUI components like `JTextField` or `JComboBox` have name property I can set by calling `setName(..)`.

Can component names contain every character? Is there any source that defines the syntax of component names?

Background: In order to let users write FitNesse tests I consider making the component properties identical to the texts of the labels next to them. But some of the labels contain spaces or symbols like hyphens, dots, commas etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use any String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29

From java source code. Component name is a String and it is said that it can be null. Setting name function does not seems to have any limitation either:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    String oldName;
    synchronized(getObjectLock()) {
        oldName = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        nameExplicitlySet = true;
    }
    firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227143/java-what-is-java-awt-component-getname-and-setname-used-for), I think you should not use these functions. If you want use the as well, any character seems acceptable. At least there is nothing in the API about forbidden characters. You might only get some problems with your look-and-feel.