# How to get and print the name of a variable which holds a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, variables, jbutton

I was wondering if it is possible to get and print a `JButton`'s name?

Given this code:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton();
```

How can I get back `button1`?

I have tried:

```
button.getName()
```

but it returns

```
null
```

Comment: Did you set a name to your button? Using `setName(String s)`. Or do you want to get the text of the button?

Comment: What does "name" mean? If you're asking whether it's possible to get the name of a field you've stored the instance in, no.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227143/java-what-is-java-awt-component-getname-and-setname-used-for

Comment: Please clarify your question greatly by telling the background information. We are usually very poor at guessing what you're thinking.

Comment: get the name of the button, for example, if I have a button called JButton button1 = new JButton(); I want to print the name of this button which is button1.

Comment: @user3288493: no, it's not possible to get an object's variable "name" because many don't even have names or are referred to by many variables, and again, you're not telling us what you're trying to do, but rather how you're trying to do it. Your question is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and only will be solved when you tell us the overall problem.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831) for which the OP seems unwilling or unable to describe the actual goal they are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess - you really want the text displayed by the JButton, not its name property. If so, check out,

```
button.getText();
// or
button.getActionCommand();
```

If you're looking for the variable name, well that is not obtainable by method call, nor should it be since an object can be referred to by many variables, or may be part of a collection or array, and so a variable name for an object is close to a meaningless concept.

Moral: clarify your question by giving us your background story, just what it is you're trying to do, not so much how you're trying to do it.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment,

> get the name of the button, for example, if I have a button called JButton button1 = new JButton(); I want to print the name of this button which is button1

You're confusing variable names with object names. `button1` above is the name of the JButton ***variable*** but not the object it refers to since objects don't have names.

It's not generally possible to get an object's variable "name" by calling a method on object, because many objects don't even have names, for instance if they're part of a collection, or a single object may be referred to by many variables, and so which "name" would be the one you desire.

For instance say you have this code:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Foo");
JButton button2 = button1;
```

What is the "name" of the JButton object created here? Both button1 and button2 refer to the *exact **same** JButton object,* and so there's no such thing as a name for an object here.

Again, you're not telling us what you're trying to do, but rather how you're trying to do it. Your question is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and only will be solved when you tell us the overall problem.

If you're trying to find out which JButton has been pressed, the ActionListener's actionPerformed ActionEvent parameter has a `getSource()` method which will return a reference to the button ***object*** that was pressed, and you can use that. How you use that will depend on the details of your problem which you need to tell us.

For example:

```
// inside of an ActionListener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  // this will get you a reference to the button object that was pressed:
  AbstractButton sourceBtn = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();

  // now you can use the sourceBtn object, or compare its reference to your 
  // JButton variables or collections in your GUI
  // for example if your GUI has buttons in a List<JButton> you could
  for (JButton button : buttonList) {
    if (sourceBtn == button) {
      // you've found your button of interest!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, so when you are looping through each buttonList, you are storing it in the variable button? which then is used in the if statement to check if it is equals to the text given in this case text of the button?

Answer (score 3):

Swing `name` properties are `null` by default. You need to set them

```
button.setName("name");
```

Comment: I have already given names to my button, there follow this rule my first button = button1, second button2, third button3 and so on.

Comment: @user3288493: you are not setting the name property of your button and are very confused about what names mean. Again, please clarify what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.

Comment: @user3288493 Please post a [Minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you are attempting

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the text on the button then you need to use the method getText(). So the solution for you would be.

```
button.getText()
```

Comment: I want to get the button name. e.g. if I have a button called JButton button1 = new JButton(); I want to print out the name of this button which is button1.