# is it possible to make if else statement code smaller?

Tags: java, if-statement

I was wondering if it would be possible to make the code below any smaller, basically its if else statement and each time only 3 things are changing and I was think I am just repeating my self, so I though if there is any way to make it any smaller.

```
if (text1.getText == "1" && text2.text == "2"){
    text3.setText("3");
}

else if(text3.getText == "1" && text4.text == "2"){
    text7.setText("3");
}

else if(text5.getText == "1" && text6.text == "2"){
    text4.setText("3");
}

else if(text7.getText == "1" && text8.text == "2"){
    text5.setText("3");
}

else if(text9.getText == "1" && text10.text == "2"){
    text6.setText("3");
}

else if(text11.getText == "1" && text12.text == "2"){
    text2.setText("3");
}

else if(text13.getText == "1" && text14.text == "2"){
    text14.setText("3");
}

......

else{
    Statement here
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` for Strings.

Comment: instead should I use equal? e.g. text1.getText.equals("1")

Comment: [Absolutely.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Should `getText` be `getText()`?

Comment: @SimonT, yes it should be, I had to rewrite the code on stackoverflow so I forgot to add that, sorry about that.

Comment: Use a collection of JTextFields such as an `ArrayList<JTextfields>`, a for loop, and as noted above a correct test of equality. I have to wonder if a JTable would  not be better here.

Comment: Using the modulus operator would make the code smaller, but it would also make it a lot more unreadable, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, could you please give me an example.

Comment: In every if block you are checking for different variables.... in such  situations... you can't reduce the code any further...  Sometimes its its better to leave the code as its for better readability than to put multiple check in one single confusing block make it more error prone and difficult to debug...

Comment: Perhaps you can create a function that takes three arguments, checks that the first two texts' values equal "1" and "2", and then sets the third text to "3". Then, make a collection of lists of text fields and iterate through it, passing the first, second, and third element of each list to the function.

Comment: I tried making a method for only the if and else if statement and then calling the method for how many times I need it but then the else statement don;t work.

Comment: Also, why should I post an answer when you have ignored the effort I put into answering [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836049/how-to-get-and-print-the-name-of-a-variable-which-holds-a-jbutton) of yours? Normally this doesn't bother, me, but I put a lot of time into that answer and you completely blew it off.

Comment: I would suggest putting the pieces of this puzzle into a Karnaugh Map and letting it reduce itself. The result is guaranteed to be the MOST simplified boolean logic possible.

Comment: You can also use equalsIgnoreCase if there is no Case Sensative issues Example:  `text1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("1") && text2.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("2")`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, sorry about that but the post was marked at off-topic and it wouldn't allow me to edit or comment on anything, the best I could do was rate the question

Comment: That question wasn't even closed, but if it were, you are allowed to 1) comment on any answer, even if the question is closed, and 2) edit your question to improve it as we suggested you do. Closed questions often get re-opened if improved. I ask that you do both of these things out of respect for the efforts others have put into trying to answer your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I am sorry for what have happened, is there anything I can do now to make you happier and not have hard feeling for me?

Comment: Please resolve the prior question. Accept the best answer, comment on the answers given.

Comment: @Suzon `equalsIgnoreCase` can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean didIt = false;
ArrayList<JTextField[]> listOfStuff = new ArrayList<JTextField[]>();
listOfStuff.add({ text1, text2, text3 });
listOfStuff.add({ text3, text4, text7 });
....
listOfStuff.add({ text13, text44, text14 });

for (JTextField[] fields : listOfStuff) {
    didIt = didIt || setToThree(fields[2], fields[0], fields[1]);
}

if (!didIt) {
    Statement here
}
```

Function:

```
boolean setToThree(JTextField target, JTextField first, JTextField second) {
    if ("1".equals(first.getText()) && "2".equals(second.getText()) {
        target.setText("3");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, BVB, could you please briefly explain the code.

Comment: I have simply created a list of lists of text fields. For each list of text fields, a function is called. If a text field is modified within the function, true is returned. This return value is read into the didIt boolean, which controls whether the "else" block from the original code should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern looks like for every pair of `textN` and `textN+1`, you set some other `textM` to `3` if the two aforementioned are labelled `1` and `2` respectively.  I don't see the pattern connecting pairs to their target texts, so I suggest this:

1. Assuming these text variables are of the type `Text`, store them using one of the following:

   - `Text[] texts = new Text[N];`
   - `ArrayList<Text> texts = new ArrayList<Text>();`
2. Put all of your `Text` instances in the array or `ArrayList`
3. Set up a map or method that takes the odd number of some pair of consecutive `Text`s and returns the target `Text` to modify (look up `HashMap`)
4. Use a `for` loop to iterate through every other `Text` instance

Here's an example, if you're using an array and some method `findTarget`:

```
for (int i = 0; i+1 < texts.length; i+=2) {
    if texts[i].getText().equals("1") && texts[i+1].getText().equals("2") {
        texts[findTarget(i)].setText("3");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do that.

```
function CheckValues (a, b, c){
    if (a.getText().equals("1") && (b.getText().equals("2")){
        c.setText("3");
    }

}
```

And then run it with:

```
CheckValues(text1,text2,text3);
CheckValues(text3,text4,text7);
CheckValues(text5,text6,text11);
```

Comment: but doing this, won't run the else statement or would it?