# trying to change the button name on click

Tags: java, swing

I have a button which I want to do something different the second time it is clicked. For this purpose I have the clicked button handler check for the button's name, and I change this name the first time it is pressed.

The button name does not change though, do I need to repack or update the buttonpanel it belongs to somehow?

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch(((JButton) e.getSource()).getName()) {
        case "TR":
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setName("Done TR");
                awaitPoints("TR");
                break;
        case "Done TR":
                CP.ComputeTransfo();
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setName("TR Complete");
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                break;
        default:
                System.out.println("ERROR:TFM01");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this text displayed to user ? if yes  DON"T USE `setName` use `setText()` instead

Comment: How do you know it doesn't change? You're not printing `getName()` after a `setName()`. In other words, what you're seeing isn't always the state of the object (despite using wrong methods)

Comment: @BasilBattikhi That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227143/what-is-java-awt-component-getname-and-setname-used-for)

Component.setName(..) is used in the JDK mostly by the look and feel implementation classes to set ID-like strings for each component, e.g. BasicOptionPaneUI might call it on a button component to set its name to "OptionPane.button".

so if you want to change the text of the label you need to use `setText()` not `setName()`

```
JButton btn=new JButton("Text Before the change");
btn.setText("This text got changed!")
```